# How to set X directly to ctx.accounts.X instead of updating ctx.accounts.X's subfields one by one?

Tags: anchor

Let's say I have an account where the data is a struct X with a lot of subfields.

In some instructions I need to set ctx.accounts.X to a default X struct.

Is there a way to replace `ctx.accounts.X`, instead of updating `ctx.accounts.X`'s subfields one by one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an account struct type (for example):

```
#[account]
pub struct MyAccount {
    pub value: u16,
}
```

you can directly assign the account data (as long as the account is marked as `mut`) with:

```
**ctx.accounts.my_account = MyAccount {
    value: 100,
};
```